# TypeError : findInfoAnos is undefined (MEAN)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack, mean

I got this error. I'm trying to simply display the content of infosAno collection into tvDb database. Here's my file :

Template HTML : (infosAno.template.html)

```
<ul>
    <div ng-repeat="element in ctrl.array" style="alignment: center;">
        <li> {{element}}</li>
    </div>
    <script>


        findInfosAno();
    </script>

</ul>
```

Component : (infosAno.component.js)

```
angular
    .module('infosAno', [])
    .component('myInfosAno', {
        controller: 'infosAnoController',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/contents/infosAno/infosAno.template.html'
    });

angular
    .module('infosAno').controller('infosAnoController',function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        console.log('La partie informations anodines est appelée !');
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.array = [
            'Anniversaire de John Doe aujourd\'hui ! ',
            'Saisir son CRA avant le 30/08 !',
            'Repas d\'équipe ce midi.',
            'Daily Scrum à 10h00 !'
        ];

    ctrl.findInfosAno = function(db, callback) {
        var cursor =db.collection['infosAno'].find( );
        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            if (doc != null) {
                console.dir(doc);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        });
    };

    });
```

And finally, here is the server file (server.js) :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/tvDb';



app.use(express.static('tv'));

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port 8080 ...');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its quite literally telling you it cant run that function: findInfosAno(); It doesnt exist.

Are you SURE you have included the file: infosAno.component.js and is it in the right place (before or after the call to the function?)

Are all the required libraries included if any?

Comment: findInfosAno is in my Controller, and this controller is called (The array in the controller is called and is displayed on my page)

Comment: i get that. but its literally telling you that it cant find what you are trying to call. findInfosAno(); is undefined......

Comment: I understand the error, I just don't get why it isn't finding even if it's defined in a controller which is correctly called :/